# Can Firebase provide a dynamic value based in part from a private key/value pair?

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to calculate data dynamically using private Firebase key/value pairs?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish -

Within Firebase, I'd like to have my AWS user credential stored as a key/value pair, e.g. AWS_ACCESS_ID = value. (I don't want my users having access to this key.) I'd then like to have a web browser (using Javascript via Firebase) read a separate key/value pair that determines its value based in part from the private AWS_ACCESS_ID key. I can't have my client first read the AWS_ACCESS_ID key b/c it would then be exposed.

In other words, a publicly exposed value is determined from a private value. Is this possible using Firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have the concept of calculated values as you describe them here. The security rules allow you to declaratively do (possibly quite complex) validations. But Firebase doesn't offer the ability to run your code on their servers to calculate derived values.

The closest you can get is by running the code that calculates the key on a server of your own. It helps to realize that "server" is a bit of a misnomer here. You can easily get started by running such code in a node.js process on your local machine or even in a browser tab.

The important thing is that this code runs under *elevated rights*, which simply means that it either uses a special "administrator" account that you created or (more likely) using the so-called *secret* that you can find in the dashboard of your Firebase. With the secret that code has access to all data, so you can then deny access to the keypair from regular users.