# Changing a particular data at a particular time everyday at 12 A.M in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developing an android app using Firebase as the backend.
assume the following path.

path(techhalls\blocks\I\405\booked)
this path results in "booked:true"

Now I want to change its value to `false` at 12 A.M everyday i.e., `booked:true` should change to `booked:false` at 12 A.M

I'm clueless here. Could any anyone help me?

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml if you are using flexible environment or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cronref if you are using standard

Comment: There is no way to schedule such automatic changes to run on the Firebase servers at the moment. This means that you will have to run a process on a server that you control to run the change. See these previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28508549, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38992583, http://stackoverflow.com/q/35360421 and the links that Linxy provided for solutions using App Engine.